# How to do this nested for loop time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, nested-loops

I'm trying to figure out this time complexity:

```
for(i=0; i<=(n/2)-1; i++){
    for (j=i+1; j<=(n/2)-1; j++){
        --some O(1) thing--                
    }   
}
```

The outer loop I understand to be on its own O(n/2.) However with the inner loop as well I can't wrap my brain around how to break down how many times O(1) executes.

If the inner one stared j=0 I could do n/2(inner) * n/2(outer) = O(n^2) time complexity right? However since j depends on i, I'm thinking some type of summation is involved from i+1 to n/2 but i can't figure out how to set it up...

Basically I need help kind of visualizing how many times it loops, and how to set the summation up. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that m = n/2. You will see that in inner loop, j will iterater over range m-1, m-2, m-3,... 1. Summing all of that will be 1+2+..+m-1 = (m-1)*m/2 = O(m^2)

Comment: 1) I don't understand why it iterates m-1,m-2...because it's not starting from 0, it's starting from i...

2) even though m = n/2, time complexity is O(n^2/4)=O(n^2) right?
3) If the O(1) had something like j+=2 would it affect the time complexity at all (since j is being iterated double)

thank you :) :)

Comment: 1) Go from 2 to m take m-1,
Go from 3 to m take m-2,
Go from 2 to m take m-3,
and so on.
2) O(n^2) is same as O(m^2) because it only different in multiply factor
3) It only affect multiply factor, which mean doesn't change anything

Comment: Wait actually I am still confused sorry haha After you take m-1,m-2,m-3 etc then adding those up is only for one loop of i isn't it? Why don't we need to multiply by outer loop O(n)...or do i still need to? Like is total (both loops) time complextity is O(n*n^2) ?

Comment: nevermind i am just getting brain fuzzled. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

### Premise

For simplicity, let us call `m = n / 2 - 1`. The outer loop runs from `0` to `m`. The inner loop from `i + 1` to `m`.

---

### Iteration counting

We need to count how often the inner statement which you labeled `O(1)` is executed. That is, how often the inner loop runs in total, as executed by the outer loop. So let us take a look.

The first iteration of the outer loop generates `m - 1` iterations of the inner loop. The second generates `m - 1`, then `m - 2`, `m - 3`, `m - 4`, ..., `2`, `1`, `0`.

That means that the `O(1)` statement is, in total, executed:

```
(m - 1) + (m - 2) + (m - 3) + ... + 2 + 1 + 0
```

That is the sum from `0` up to `m - 1`

```
sum_{i = 0}^{m - 1} i
```

which can be simplified to

```
(m^2 - m) / 2
```

---

### Substitute back

Let us now substitute back `m = n / 2 - 1`, we get

```
((n / 2 - 1)^2 - (n / 2 - 1)) / 2
```

After simplifying, this is

```
n^2/8 - 3n/4 + 1
```

---

### Big-O

For Big-O, we observe that it is smaller than

```
  n^2 - 0 + n^2
= 2n^2
```

Which, by definition is `O(n^2)`.

As you see, this bound is also tight. So we also receive `Omega(n^2)` which also concludes `Theta(n^2)`.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer :)

If you don't mind I have an extension question: For my whole code (more than what I posted) I got T(n) = 2T(n/2) + O(n/2) + O(n^2). I want to double check I am finding the asymptotic upper bound correctly. Can i use masters theorum here since O(n) and O(n^2) are both polynomial multiples of n^log2(2)? I was going to do T(n) = theta(nlog2(n)) [from case 2 O(n)] + theta(n^2) [from case 3 O(n^2)]. If wrong then what approach i should use?? thank you :)